# How to integrate GWT with ASP.NET MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, gwt

I already have an *[ASP.NET MVC3](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3)* website, using *[Razor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ASP.NET_Razor_View_Engine)* as the *Views engine*.
Is it possible to create the UI using *[GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)* and invoke it as a *View* in my *MVC3* website?
How is it done correctly?

Note: I know it easier to use JS API's such as JQuery or Google Closure to build UI in ASP.NET MVC3, but currently GWT is a requirement for the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is whether you want to go down the multi-page or the single-page road.
GWT is a toolkit which helps you create single page web-applications where the backend only serves as a datasource. This is a [SOUI](http://www.infoq.com/news/2007/11/soui-death-of-mvc2) (Service Oriented User Interface) approach.

A single host page serves the GWT client application and you deal with flow synchronization and other user interface pattern (MVP) on the client side.
If you go down this road, you will probably not use any of ASP.NET MVC3's advanced features (specifically the model controller view part).

However it is also possible to use GWT in a multi-page setup where the backend takes care of the "flow synchronization" and you embed GWT as widgets in the corresponding views/pages.
You end up with small GWT apps for each host page/MVC view. You won't get all the optimizations in code-reuse because each host page will be a separate GWT app and thus shared code will be downloaded multiple times.

Regarding your specific question and the technical aspects of ASP.NET MVC3 and Razor:
I can't really comment on that because I don't have experience with ASP.NET MVC3. But in general GWT apps can be embedded in any web-page by simple including the nocache.js bootstrap file (if you want history support also embed the hidden iFrame).
See [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideHostPage) for  more details.

Note: this [project](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-multipage/) could be also of interest to you.